# Can't run FlashPlayerUpdateService.exe by Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-7, flash-player

My Windows 7 Utimate 64 bit has some problems with the Flash Player update.

In Services, it always switch to manual. In Task Scheduler, I added a new task but it never runs.

Here are the export XML.

[Expost.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F357l.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2016-05-17T15:13:42.5855037</Date>
    <Author>TONG-PC\Tong</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <UserId>TONG-PC\Tong</UserId>
      <Delay>PT2M</Delay>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>TONG-PC\Tong</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerUpdateService.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, It can run already. I tried out for a whole day. And found a solution.

1. It must create with basic task first.
2. Don't use more than 2 whitespaces in the name. Very very strange.
3. Reboot to test and it will work well
4. Now adjust some options, such as delay, repeat, etc.